# Taking local Jersey REST service to openshift

Tags: java, git, rest, jersey, openshift

I have a REST service, that uses Jersey, deployed on my local machine. The service does not use an ORM. Instead, it uses the JDBC driver to populate models from my MYSQL database. Everything is working as expected and now, I would like to deploy my service onto Openshift. I have read up on how Openshift works and I'm a little confused. I do not have any experience with GIT, so I found myself getting lost when the Openshift website told me to push my application to their servers via GIT.

I am looking to have my REST service, as well as MYSQL database moved to the Openshift server without making changes to my existing code. This is my first time deploying a web service on something other than localhost so any leads, regarding what to do research on to get what I want would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer able to help you? Do you still need any help with this?

Comment: Yes It helped. I was able to work it out by following the steps on the link. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Open-shift is a fantastic service, its just sometimes difficult to figure out how to use, kind of like almost everything in the technological world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using OpenShift to host some personal projects, and I can feel your pain when you get a little lost with how to do it. I had been using Git for awhile though so that helped.

[This page.](https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install) is what helped me get the tools set up for git correctly. They require ruby, and node, so you'll have to install those as well. Once you get everything set up though, you'll basically "Clone" the repository that open shift gives you which will create a local instance of the repositories contents in your computer. You can then use the commands "git add", "git commit" and "git push" which will push your changes back up to their server.

Good instructions exist on [this page](https://www.openshift.com/get-started) describing what I just told you. From what you said it looks like you've completed steps 1 + 2, but steps 3 and 4 are still left. You have to have your command line tools set up first however. Let me know if it helps!